# Spring Batch | Multiple files

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch to manipulate data in CSV files. So there are 3 files in folder1, files1, file2, file3. I have written 3 steps for perform the operation i.e.
Step1 : read from file 1 , process file 1 and write file 1
Step2 : read from file2 , process file2 and write file 2
Step3 : read from file 3, process file 3 and write file 3

Now there are 9 more similar folders. I need to perform same manipulations on files inside each folder.

One way to do the same can be passing directory path as parameter to the job and calling job for all the folders. Is there any better way to do it ?

Comment: Why do you have a step per file? Are the files similar or are there 3 types of file in each folder? This is key to correctly answer your question.

Comment: There are 3 types of files in each folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partitioned step, with a partition per folder. You would have 9 partitions in your case. Each worker step could be defined as a flow of  the 3 steps required to process input files.

You can find more details and a code example of how to implement a partitioned step in the documentation here: [Partitioning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning).